# R replace duplicated values with sequential text string

Tags: r

I have a data frame in the following format:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
ID1234  123     5
ID1456  396     5
ID8572  345     7
ID7234  645     7
ID1247  356     5
ID1256  122     5
```

And want to create a loop over Column3 that will replace the dublicates and make the frame like this:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
ID1234  123     5       Tag1
ID1456  396     5       Tag2
ID8572  345     7       Tag1
ID7234  645     7       Tag2
ID1247  356     5       Tag1
ID1256  122     5       Tag2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what happens if the same value appears (duplicate) more than once (if that makes sense). For example consider the data frame,

```
  Column1 Column2 Column3
1  ID1234     123       5
2  ID1456     396       5
3  ID8572     345       7
4  ID7234     645       7
5  ID1247     356       5
6  ID1256     122       5
```

Do you want to do the sequence for duplicates or consecutive duplicates?

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Column3) != 0))) %>% 
  mutate(res = paste0('Tag', row_number())) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 4
>   Column1 Column2 Column3 res  
>   <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>
> 1 ID1234      123       5 Tag1 
> 2 ID1456      396       5 Tag2 
> 3 ID8572      345       7 Tag1 
> 4 ID7234      645       7 Tag2 
> 5 ID1247      356       5 Tag1 
> 6 ID1256      122       5 Tag2
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much indeed I wanted the population to be made like the bottom table you pasted. I edited my question to clarify to other readers.

Comment: about what? your solution seems to work in my actual data. I didn't have more than 2 duplicates in Column3 but I do want the code to account for the scenario you described in your bottom table. That's why I edited my question :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realize the changes. Is your current response accounting for this scenario?

Comment: Yes it is. So does the one you accepted (not mine)...but the time you accepted it, it wasn't, that's why I asked. Anw, no worries. All answers now account for that scenario.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `ave` and create a sequential row id for each group.

```
df$Column4 <- paste0("Tag", with(df, ave(Column1, Column3, FUN = seq_along)))

df
#  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
#1  ID1234     123       5    Tag1
#2  ID1456     396       5    Tag2
#3  ID8572     345       7    Tag1
#4  ID7234     645       7    Tag2
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Column3) %>%
  mutate(Column4 = paste0("Tag", row_number()))
```

and `data.table`

```
setDT(df)[, Column4 := paste0("Tag", seq_len(.N)), by = Column3]
```

---

For the updated data, if we want to reset the counter every time the value changes, we can do

```
df %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(Column3 != lag(Column3, default = first(Column3)))) %>%
  mutate(Column4 = paste0("Tag", row_number())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)
```

and with `data.table`

```
setDT(df)[, Column4 := paste0("Tag", seq_len(.N)), by = rleid(Column3)]
```

Comment: Yes @RonakShah added a `dplyr` solution similar to mine, so I deleted it due it seemed to me useless having such slight different answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Column4 := paste0("Tag", rowid(rleid(Column3)))]
df1
#   Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
#1:  ID1234     123       5    Tag1
#2:  ID1456     396       5    Tag2
#3:  ID8572     345       7    Tag1
#4:  ID7234     645       7    Tag2
#5:  ID1247     356       5    Tag1
#6:  ID1256     122       5    Tag2
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Column4 = str_c("Tag", rowid(rleid(Column3))))
# Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
#1  ID1234     123       5    Tag1
#2  ID1456     396       5    Tag2
#3  ID8572     345       7    Tag1
#4  ID7234     645       7    Tag2
#5  ID1247     356       5    Tag1
#6  ID1256     122       5    Tag2
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
df1$Column4 <- paste0("Tag", ave(1:nrow(df1),  
   with(rle(df1$Column3), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)), FUN = seq_along))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Column1 = c("ID1234", "ID1456", "ID8572", "ID7234", 
"ID1247", "ID1256"), Column2 = c(123L, 396L, 345L, 645L, 356L, 
122L), Column3 = c(5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```